# Google drive api file upload issue using swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, google-drive-api

i am unable to upload file in my google drive using swift 3 there is no error but still file is not uploading.

```
 let folder = GTLRDrive_File()
    folder.name = "hellokitty"
    folder.mimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"
    let query1 = GTLRDriveQuery_FilesCreate.query(withObject: folder, uploadParameters: nil)
    query1.fields = "demo"
    service.executeQuery(query1, completionHandler: {(ticket:GTLRServiceTicket,file:GTLRDrive_File,error:Error?)-> Void in

        if error == nil {
            print("file id",file.identifier as Any)
        }else{
            print("error occured",error as Any)
        }


        } as? GTLRServiceCompletionHandler)
```

Comment: Try to use the sample code in [this GitHub post](https://github.com/baby03201/iOS-Swift-GoogleDriveSample). You can also refer in [this documentation for swift](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/ios?ver=swift) to have a further info about the functionality you needed to implement.

Comment: i have seen both code but both code are old. New google pods not supporting class that used both code.